# Вставка элемента в карту без оператора присваивания

Tags: c++, map

Не получается сделать карту, которая по номеру `id` возвращает экземпляр моего класса. Вот код:

```
struct Ref {
    Ref(int& x) : x{x} {}

    int& x;
};

#include <map>

int main() {
    int x, y, z;
    std::map<int, Ref> ref_by_id;

    ref_by_id[0] = Ref{x};
    ref_by_id[1] = Ref{y};
    ref_by_id[2] = Ref{y};
}
```

Выводит ошибку:

> error C2280: 'Ref &Ref::operator =(const Ref &)': attempting to
> reference a deleted function

Пробовал не использовать `=`, а вызывать конструктор `ref_by_id[0]{Ref{x}};`, но тоже не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно заполняете, оператор [] сначала создает элемент с конструктором по-умолчанию, а потом возвращает его. Соответственно попытка присвоить существующему элементу новое значение буден заведомо неудачной. Вместо этого следует сразу при создании элемента передавать нужную ссылку:

```
ref_by_id.emplace
(
    ::std::piecewise_construct
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple(0)
,   ::std::forward_as_tuple(x)
);
```

Comment: А что такое `::std::piecewise_construct` и `::std::forward_as_tuple`?

Comment: @mustafa https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct это параметры, вызывающие перегрузку, которая форвардит две пачки параметров в конструкторы ключа и значения

Comment: Попробовал просто `ref_by_id.emplace(0, Ref{x});` и работает!

Answer (score 0):

ссылки или классы содержащие ссылки не могут быть содержимым стандартных контейнеров, так как для них не определен оператор присваивания, потому что ссылка должна быть инициализирована во время создания, поэтому я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону указателей

возможная реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

struct Ref {
  Ref() = default;
  Ref(std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

  std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<int> x = std::make_shared<int>(5);
  std::shared_ptr<int> y = std::make_shared<int>(10);
  std::shared_ptr<int> z = std::make_shared<int>(15);
  std::map<int, Ref> ref_by_id;

  ref_by_id.insert({ 0, x });
  ref_by_id.insert({ 1, y });
  ref_by_id.insert({ 2, z });

  std::cout << *ref_by_id[0].ptr << '\n';
  std::cout << *ref_by_id[1].ptr << '\n';
  std::cout << *ref_by_id[2].ptr << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сейчас создаете временное значение, затем сохраняете ссылку на него, затем временное значение удаляется, а ссылка остается. Оно вообще не может работать правильно. Вам нужно либо корректно определить конструкторы, либо использовать `std::reference_wrapper`.

Или

```
int value= 2;
std::tuple<int&> ref = std::tie(value)
```